# Resize Silverlight application to fit window

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011

I have created a silverlight application that has been placed on an entity form and currently it has been set to a fixed width. What i'm after is for the application, including the datagrid and pagers that are in it, to stretch to the width of the window.

So far i've been unable to find anything that works so I was hoping that someone would be able to help me with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You Should Try To Column width And Row Hight "Auto" And Also You Should Try StackPanal To Fix This Problem

Answer (score 0):

Try use Stackpanel in your silverlight page and place all of controls in stackpanel and set it's width to "Auto".